# Multiple ajax calls in the same moment to c# static webMethod

Tags: ajax, request, webmethod

I have a problem with multiple ajax calls in the same moment to c# static webMethod.
I never thought about it but now i can see with my eyes that it's maybe a problem..
If two users request at the same time the same webmethod the response of user2 is the same of the user1.. For example:

- user1 requests the products with a type1 filter
- user2 requsts the products with a type2 filter

I can see that user1 receives the right results but user2 receive the same results of user1 that is not the right one!

User1 and User2 call the same webmethod from 2 different browsers.

Is it possible? How can i fix it? Must i create a "requests manager" in each webmethod?
Thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i made a lot of specific test and the results say that is not an ajax problem... so i think my methods are the problem! (maybe because it refers to static variabiles external to my webMethods like ObjectContext)